# trigger email google firestore extension

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, smtp, handlebars.js

I have an angular app that I'm using with firebase. I've setup a contact form for people to reach out to me - and I am to receive these messages as emails through the firestore. I'm using the trigger email extension. I am receiving the emails, however, I'm not getting all the info from the input fields.

```
  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Your form data : ', this.contactForm.value );
    const {contactFormName, contactFormEmail, contactFormSubject, contactFormMessage} = this.contactForm.value;

    this.af.collection('mail').add({
      to: '#####@gmail.com',
      message :{
  //    name: this.contactForm.value.contactFormName,
  //    email: this.contactForm.value.contactFormEmail,
      subject: this.contactForm.value.contactFormSubject,
      text: this.contactForm.value.contactFormMessage
    }

  })
  .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.contactForm.reset();
  })
  .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
  })
}}
```

Firestore allows only fields like message,HTML and text as default. I'd like to customize the emails so that the name + the email to show up in the body of the email as well but it doesn't. Firestore suggests using handlebars to do this but I'm unclear on how. Here's a link for reference:

https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to find out how to use handlebars to customize the body of an email created by using the trigger email extension.

You may use a statement similar to:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

and then choose a layout that is suitable in the email context. You may have a look at the whole example on the [functions-samples/template-handlebars/functions/index.js](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/template-handlebars/functions/index.js) page.

For actual layout examples, you may check [A Step By Step Guide To Using Handlebars With Your Node js App](https://medium.com/@waelyasmina/a-guide-into-using-handlebars-with-your-express-js-application-22b944443b65).